# retrieving the id from bootstrap table using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using MVC 5 for my web application project. And i created an inbuilt list of the table done by MVC itself. Now i want to get the id of the data i have clicked. MVC itself creates a edit/delete option but i want to make the whole row an clickable one so that when i press one of the row then i would link me to the details of that id.
problem is i can't pass the id to the javascript at all when i click the row. i tried to search it and i found something like this var id = $('.clickableRow').attr("data-id");
but it only shows undefined value.

Here my index.cshtml source code

```
@foreach (var item in Model){
<tr id="clickableRow(this)">
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SentBy)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SentTo)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Subject)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SentDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message)
    </td>
    <td>

        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.MailId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.MailId })
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

and here the javascript i tried to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.clickableRow').on('click', function (e) {
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.SentBy').html();
        //var id = $('.clickableRow').attr("data-id");
        alert(id);
        //window.location = "Mails/Details/" + id;
        // Or, we can grab the HREF from the first anchor:
        //window.location = $('a:first', this).attr('href');
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: post your generated html

Answer (score 0):

You have `<tr id="clickableRow(this)">` which seems to (incorrectly) assume that the `id` attribute is an event like `onclick`. Additionally, you are attempting to access the id as a `data` attribute, which would require it be prefixed with `data-`, i.e. `data-id` and I'm not sure where the `.clickableRow` class is coming from as there aren't any classes being assigned to the example row.

I don't know anything about .NET, but you should put the actual record ID in a `data-id` attribute:

`<tr class="clickableRow" data-id="OUTPUT_ID_HERE">`

```
$(function(){
    $('table').on('click', '.clickableRow', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $this.data('id');  
        alert(id);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript you are trying to access a `class` element, where as in your HTML you have defined an `ID` attribute.

Try changing your JavaScript to this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#clickableRow').on('click', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var id=$this.attr("data-id");
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

Comment: Have a look at this ,http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquey-make-entire-table-row-clickable/ it is not .NET specific, but you could use the same concept and implement the same !!